# JavaScript framework for desktop touch screen applications?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, web

Are there frameworks out there to help design rich UX for non-mobile touch screen devices e.g. a kiosk in a retail outlet?

Comment: afaik, taps on touch screen monitors register as clicks. it shouldn't be any different from a desktop using a mouse, therefore desktop frameworks should work the same.

Comment: Right, but I'm thinking more look and feel. Bigger buttons, easy navigation. Mobile principals, but without the constraints.

Comment: Fair enough...I'm looking to use SO as more of a discovery engine in this case since Google has provided almost 100% mobile solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay device agnostic and use [Responsive Design](http://thinkvitamin.com/design/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design/): [320andUp](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/), [Bootstrap](http://www.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/) are two responsive frameworks that curtail to touch devices - a desktop touch should not be much different from a tablet touch device in terms of dimensions and UX/UI.

Answer (score -1):

From my investigation so far, [Microsoft Surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh241326.aspx) is the only solution that fully supports my multi-touch touch screen. The [Microsoft Touch Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17368) is a bunch of beautiful apps written using Surface. Obviously ties you to Windows and also requires the XNA framework and C# 4.0.

I see from your tags that you were hoping for a javascript framework. I was too, but unfortunately there are none that I am aware of that fully support a multi-touch desktop touch screen. [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is for small screens (e.g. full window width buttons). [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) does not fully support desktop touch screens (e.g. no drag and drop in Chrome) and is aimed at mobile. However maybe they are functional enough to fulfill your requirements?

I have not yet installed Windows 8, but it is supposed to be at least styled for touch screens, so...